# New Command with carriage return

Tags: renewcommand

Good morning everyone!
Still for my theater script template, I created the `\move` command for captions, but I can't set the carriage return (see figure). However, the text must keep in line with the rest. Is this possible? Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\move{\par\vskip0mm \noindent\makebox[35mm][l]{}\hangindent=35mm\textsl}

\def\declname#1#2{%
\def#1{\vskip5mm \noindent\hbox to35mm{#2\hss}\hangindent=35mm \ignorespaces}}
\declname \JAMES {JAMES}

\begin{document}

\JAMES
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit lorem ipsum dolor.
\move{(Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit.)}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
\move{(Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcorper)}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit lorem ipsum dolor.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: presumably you want `\par` at the end of your `\move` definition, but why is this all defined using primitves such as `\vskip`, `\hangindent`, rather than a latex list?

Comment: Besides doing it on your own: Did you have a look at the drama topic at ctan https://ctan.org/topic/drama-script ?

Comment: Using your current approach, you can extend `move` command to: `\newcommand\move[1]{\par\vskip0mm\noindent\makebox[35mm][l]{}\hangindent=35mm\textsl{#1}\par\noindent\makebox[35mm][l]{}\hangindent=35mm}`.

Comment: This is one of the very few situations where using a double backslash `\\ ` to end a line is appropriate.  Redefining the carriage return can be dangerous, and is not a good idea.

Comment: @barbarabeeton only if `\move[aaa}` is always followed by more text, just using `\par` (without a following `\noindent` as in the previous comment)is preferable.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- I agree that in this case, `\par` is preferable.  But the other *is* possible, and I believe that it's good to know *when* the double backslash may be acceptable in order to know when *not* to use it.  Note that I don't intend to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a slanted paragraph, with suitable margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\leftskip{35mm}% really should be a list

\newcommand\move[1]{%
\par\textsl{#1}\par}

\newcommand\declname[2]{%
\def#1{%
\par\vspace{5mm}%
\noindent\hspace{-35mm}\makebox[35mm][l]{#2}}}

\declname \JAMES {JAMES}

\begin{document}

\JAMES
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit lorem ipsum dolor.
\move{(Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit.)}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
\move{(Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcorper)}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit lorem ipsum dolor.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd add structure to the thing. For instance, the various lengths should be parameters, so you can easily change them for experiments in a centralized fashion.

Another suggestion is to make the theater script part an environment, so you can add parts typeset in a different style.

I also propose a simpler way to declare names: without an optional argument, the name is taken to be also the command name, but you can decide for a different command name by adding the optional argument (see the example).

Sorry for changing `\textsl` into `\textit`, but I find slanted type really awful. Also, the outer parentheses should be part of the command definition and upright (but that's my taste).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\newenvironment{script}
 {%
  \par
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  \setlength{\leftskip}{\scriptleftmargin}
 }
 {\par}

\newcommand{\namebox}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \makebox[\scriptleftmargin][l]{#1}%
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\declname}{O{#2}m}{%
  \ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{#1}{%
    \par\addvspace{\nameskip}%
    \namebox{#2}%
  }%
}

\newcommand\move[1]{\par(\textit{#1})\par}

\newlength{\scriptleftmargin}
\newlength{\nameskip}

\setlength{\scriptleftmargin}{35mm}
\setlength{\nameskip}{5mm}

\declname{JAMES}
\declname[OOC]{ÖÖÇ}

\begin{document}

\begin{script}

\JAMES
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit lorem ipsum dolor.
\move{Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit.}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy 
nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
\move{Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcorper}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit lorem ipsum dolor.

\OOC
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit lorem ipsum dolor.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit lorem ipsum dolor.

\end{script}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why not `\hangindent`? Because it's reset at every paragraph. It would be possible to set it again, but it's simpler to use `\leftskip`.

Comment: Do you have any idea to the [pronunciation problem](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/14129/8870) for an Italian name？